# Strange spark ERROR on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a really simple PySpark script that creates a dataframe from some parquet data on S3 and then call `count()` method and print out the number of records.

I run the script on AWS EMR cluster and I'm seeing following strange WARN information:

```
17/12/04 14:20:26 WARN ServletHandler: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:164)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.MetricHelper.submetricQuantiles(AllStagesResource.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$$anon$1.build(AllStagesResource.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$.taskMetricDistributions(AllStagesResource.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStage(OneStageResource.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStageAttempt(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.taskSummary(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ... 28 more
17/12/04 14:20:26 WARN HttpChannel: //ip-172-31-81-10.ec2.internal:4040/api/v1/applications/application_1512395256824_0002/stages/3/0/taskSummary?proxyapproved=true
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:164)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.MetricHelper.submetricQuantiles(AllStagesResource.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$$anon$1.build(AllStagesResource.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$.taskMetricDistributions(AllStagesResource.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStage(OneStageResource.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStageAttempt(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.taskSummary(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
```

It seems like it does not fail the job, though. I got the count returned successfully.

Just wonder if anyone know why this happens and how to get rid of it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating multiple `SparkContext`s by any chance ?

Comment: No I have only one SparkContext.

Comment: I have also been getting this error and would love to know if you find a resolution. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't found anything yet. Since it's not failing the job I'd simply ignore the warning for now even though it's annoying. I'll let you know once I find anything.

Comment: I just ran into this after upgrading to emr 5.10.0. Running exactly the same code on 5.9.0 did not throw the error. In my case I'm using scala and actually calling .get on an option, so the error makes more sense, but I'm always calling it in a safe manner and should never get this error. Plus, my code still seems to work just fine.

Comment: I am also getting this error when running the EMR cluster in a VPC with a VPN connection to our corporate data center. When I run the same code on an EMR cluster with the default VPC, the error does not appear. I suspect some DNS configuration issues.

Comment: Same issue here and also seems tied to upgrading to EMR 5.10 it does not happen on 5.9 so is there a chance your other cluster happens to be earlier than 5.10 and not something to do with VPC? @MariusIon

Comment: @TimGautier Now that 5.11.0 is out do you see it with that one as well?

Comment: @Traveler I am still seeing this error with EMR 5.11.0

Comment: @seiya Thank you for the update.  Have you tried downgrading to 5.9.0 ?

Comment: @TimGautier I found that a downgrade to 5.9.0 did make this exception go away.

Comment: Same problem here, EMR 5.11.0, get this error and is random, it has nothing to do with data etc.

Is downgrading to 5.9.0 the workaround ?

Comment: I've been getting this error and add this line to my scripts to remove this from REPL shell: `sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")` I'm writing in scala language though. This doesn't root cause the issue but at least removes the warning message(s) for now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those warning messages can be suppressed by adding the following lines to `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel=ERROR

log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler=ERROR
```

I didn't see any impact on performance nor on job stability.
Now my logs are much readable :)

Comment: **@Guy Cohen** I'm still getting these warning messages in `EMR 5.12.0` despite adding the above lines in said file (`Spark 2.3.0`). I'd like to tell that I found these lines already present in the file: `log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN` &
`log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR`. Should I remove them?

Answer (score 6):

For those who use AWS EMR with Spark, I also got the same error message when executing my Spark jobs in

- emr-5.10.0
- emr-5.11.0
- emr-5.11.1
- emr-5.12.0

Simply downgrading to `emr-5.9.0` will help you to solve this problem.

Hope it helps.