# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I get the error in my program while running using spark-submit in AWS EMR. Well, I could say this doesn't block my program run entirely. It kicks off after getting stuck there for 10-15 minutes. Any help will be highly appreciated.

This issue was not there in the AWS EMR v5.9.0 But it is there in 5.10.0 and 5.11.0. Is this a version issue or some generic spark issue or is there something wrong going down there?

```
18/01/04 14:20:26 WARN ServletHandler: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:164)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.MetricHelper.submetricQuantiles(AllStagesResource.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$$anon$1.build(AllStagesResource.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$.taskMetricDistributions(AllStagesResource.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStage(OneStageResource.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStageAttempt(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.taskSummary(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ... 28 more
18/01/04 14:20:26 WARN HttpChannel: //ip-172-31-81-10.ec2.internal:4040/api/v1/applications/application_1512395256824_0002/stages/3/0/taskSummary?proxyapproved=true
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:164)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:461)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.MetricHelper.submetricQuantiles(AllStagesResource.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$$anon$1.build(AllStagesResource.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.AllStagesResource$.taskMetricDistributions(AllStagesResource.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$taskSummary$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource$$anonfun$withStageAttempt$1.apply(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStage(OneStageResource.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.withStageAttempt(OneStageResource.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.taskSummary(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
```

Comment: Seems to downgrade to 5.9.0 helps ...

Comment: Did you see any impact of this on the objective of the task?

Comment: This question seems to be asked/answered in a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635510/strange-spark-error-on-aws-emr).

Answer (score 3):

This is warning messages,so you can suppress this by adding the following lines in /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties

> log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel=ERROR
>   log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler=ERROR

I am using EMR 5.12.0 version and having this warning message and didn't see any issues except this log message.