# Running chained queries using structured streaming (PySpark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

My code is something like

```
df = spark.readStream.option("header","true") \
    .schema(df_schema)\
    .csv(df_file)
df2 = df.filter(df.col == 1)
df3 = df2.withColumn("new_col", udf_f(df2.some_col))
dfc = df3.where(df3.new_col == 2).count()
query = dfc.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

I get the error message `Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()` at the `dfc` line but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does Spark structured streaming not support chained queries like this? I'm not doing any branches as per my knowledge.

EDIT:

By removing `count()` from the `dfc` line, I got a new error `StreamingQueryException: Exception thrown in awaitResult` arising from the `query.awaitTermination()` call. Any idea why `count()` did not work and also why the new error arose?

EDIT 2:

If I log to console directly without running all the intermediate queries after df, it works. However, every time I try to run an additional query, the `StreamingQueryException` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of [structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#overview) it's not possible get the count in the same way as for static data frames. When a stream is created Spark is polling sources using [trigger](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers) for a new data. If there is any Spark splits it up to small DataFrames (micro-batches) and passes along the stream (transformation, aggregation, output).

If you need to get number of records you can to add a [listener to get progress updates](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#reporting-metrics-programmatically-using-asynchronous-apis) and get number of inputs in `onQueryProgress(QueryProgressEvent event)`.

It's hard to say why you are getting `StreamingQueryException` since `filter()` and `withColumn()` work properly in structured streaming. 
Did you see other errors in console that could cause `Exception thrown in awaitResult`?

By the way, if you have multiple streams in a single session you should use `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()` to block until any one of them terminates.

The following query should work properly:

```
query = spark.readStream
    .option("header","true") \
    .schema(df_schema)\
    .csv(df_file)\
    .filter(df.col == 1)\
    .withColumn("new_col", udf_f(df2.some_col))\
    .writeStream\
    .format("console")\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
# or spark.streams().awaitAnyTermination()
```

Comment: Thank you.

The error causing the exception is

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)`

If I remove the streaming component, that is, if I sample the data, the code works.

Comment: I also used a `join` on the dataframe. Does that impact anything?

Comment: The error you get looks like a [warning in metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635510/strange-spark-error-on-aws-emr) that doesn't affect spark data processing. If you are using AWS EMR then should try to downgrade it to 5.9.0 or just suppress the warning.

Comment: You can join static data frames to a stream and starting from Spark 2.3 [stream-stream joins](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins) are supported. If you are using EMR then you should wait a bit for a new version of EMR since the latest one has Spark 2.2.1 only.

Comment: My error terminates the job. I get

`..: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(statefulOperators.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(statefulOperators.scala:172)`

Comment: Is it perhaps because I joined two of the same frames?

`x = df.select(df.col).limit(n)`
`y = df.join(x, ['col'], 'leftsemi')`

I initialise `x` before the stream starts.

Comment: ^ Not the issue. Tried changing it to another dataframe and it didn't work as well.